# Using synonyms with Oracle package

Tags: oracle, package, synonym

I created a synonym for a package, but I can't do anything with it, including a simple desc command. Check out the codes:

**Create package sql (executed on owner user)**

```
create or replace PACKAGE pkg_elmah$log_error
IS
    PROCEDURE LogError
    (
        v_ErrorId IN elmah$error.errorid%TYPE,
        v_Application IN elmah$error.application%TYPE,
        v_Host IN elmah$error.host%TYPE,
        v_Type IN elmah$error.type%TYPE,
        v_Source IN elmah$error.source%TYPE,
        v_Message IN elmah$error.message%TYPE,
        v_User IN elmah$error.username%TYPE,
        v_AllXml IN elmah$error.allxml%TYPE,
        v_StatusCode IN elmah$error.statuscode%TYPE,
        v_TimeUtc IN elmah$error.timeutc%TYPE
    );

END pkg_elmah$log_error;
```

**Create synonym and test sql (executed on not owner user)**

```
CREATE SYNONYM pkg_elmah$log_error FOR DRSP.pkg_elmah$log_error; 
desc pkg_elmah$log_error; 
---------RESULT: object does not exist
execute pkg_elmah$log_error.logerror;
---------RESULT: identifier pkg_elmah$log_error must be declared
```

These codes run fine when I log in with the owner of these objects.

Grant was given as follows (I seem unable to give to the procedure only, as it gives an ORA-04042, so I gave it to the package):

```
grant execute on PKG_ELMAH$LOG_ERROR to not_owner
```

*Environment: WINDOWS 7 64bits; SQL DEVELOPER 4.0.3.16; ORACLE CLIENT 11.2*

**Details of the synonym:**
[image: Details of the synonym.]

**Details of the package:**
  [image: package details]

Comment: I assume you provided a grant execute to the synonym owner, right?

Comment: I gave the grant to the package, as I seem unable to do it for the procedure only.

Comment: add the schema to the command `CREATE SYNONYM [SCHEMA].pkg_elmah$log_error FOR DRSP.pkg_elmah$log_error; `

Comment: Tried that, the errors are the same.

Comment: Are you sure you actually executed the grant, and haven't - say - dropped and recreated the package afterwards? You will still get PLS-00306 from your call, but the PLS-00201 should go away with the grant in place. (You could try reconnecting as not-owner after the grant, but that shouldn't be necessary).

Comment: I think APC provided correct answer

Answer (score 2):

You are doing something in the wrong order or have otherwise omitted to tell us something. Because the instructions carried out in the right order work as expected:

```
SQL> conn a/a
Connected.
USER is "A"
SQL> create or replace PACKAGE pkg_elmah$log_error
  2  IS
  3    PROCEDURE LogError
  4      (
  5        v_ErrorId IN number,
  6        v_Application IN varchar2,
  7        v_Host IN varchar2,
  8        v_Type IN varchar2,
  9        v_Source IN varchar2,
 10        v_Message IN varchar2,
 11        v_User IN varchar2,
 12        v_AllXml IN varchar2,
 13        v_StatusCode IN varchar2,
 14        v_TimeUtc IN date
 15      );
 16
 17  END pkg_elmah$log_error;  
 18  /

Package created.

SQL> grant execute on PKG_ELMAH$LOG_ERROR to b
  2  /

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn b/b
Connected.
USER is "B"
SQL> CREATE SYNONYM pkg_elmah$log_error FOR A.pkg_elmah$log_error;

Synonym created.

SQL> desc pkg_elmah$log_error 
PROCEDURE LOGERROR
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 V_ERRORID                      NUMBER                  IN
 V_APPLICATION                  VARCHAR2                IN
 V_HOST                         VARCHAR2                IN
 V_TYPE                         VARCHAR2                IN
 V_SOURCE                       VARCHAR2                IN
 V_MESSAGE                      VARCHAR2                IN
 V_USER                         VARCHAR2                IN
 V_ALLXML                       VARCHAR2                IN
 V_STATUSCODE                   VARCHAR2                IN
 V_TIMEUTC                      DATE                    IN

SQL> exec pkg_elmah$log_error.logerror
BEGIN pkg_elmah$log_error.logerror; END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'LOGERROR'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


SQL>
```